# Remove the first bracket from nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as follow:

```
let data =[
  [
    {
      "Id": "110d611c-54e4-4593-a835-def0f34ed882",
      "duration": 30,
      "name": "burger",
      "price": 10,
      
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Id": "edc241e9-5caf-4f0b-b6ea-6cf5fc57d260",
      "duration": 10,
      "name": "Cake",
      "price": 5,
      
    }
  ]
]
```

I am trying to remove the first bracket to be like this:

```
let data =

     [
        {
          "Id": "110d611c-54e4-4593-a835-def0f34ed882",
          "duration": 30,
          "name": "burger",
          "price": 10,
          
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "Id": "edc241e9-5caf-4f0b-b6ea-6cf5fc57d260",
          "duration": 10,
          "name": "Cake",
          "price": 5,
          
        }
      ]
```

I have trying many solutions, the most common one i have tried is using this way:

```
let newData = data[0]
```

but the result always giving me the first nested array something like this:

```
  [
    {
      "Id": "110d611c-54e4-4593-a835-def0f34ed882", 
      "duration": 30, 
      "name": "burger", 
      "price": 10
    }
  ]
```

I tried to convert it to string using `JSON.stringify()` then remove the bracket by doing

```
JSON.stringify(data).substring(1, JSON.stringify(data).length - 1);
```

But then when i parse it i get this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string
```

I am really stuck on what the best way to accomplish it.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Your desired result isn't valid.

Comment: That is not possible, An array is collection of values. You just can't remove `[` and `]`

Answer (score 1):

You want the first element of each nested array, not the first element of the outer array. So use `map()`.

```js
let data = [
  [{
    "Id": "110d611c-54e4-4593-a835-def0f34ed882",
    "duration": 30,
    "name": "burger",
    "price": 10,

  }],
  [{
    "Id": "edc241e9-5caf-4f0b-b6ea-6cf5fc57d260",
    "duration": 10,
    "name": "Cake",
    "price": 5,

  }]
];

let newData = data.map(el => el[0]);
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the external bracket will result in an invalid javascript object.

To obtain a single array with all the objects you can use `flatMap`

```
data.flatMap(x => x)
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Answer (score 0):

The result that you want is not valid, instead you can get array of object using [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) as:

```
data.flat()
```

```js
let data = [
  [
    {
      Id: "110d611c-54e4-4593-a835-def0f34ed882",
      duration: 30,
      name: "burger",
      price: 10,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      Id: "edc241e9-5caf-4f0b-b6ea-6cf5fc57d260",
      duration: 10,
      name: "Cake",
      price: 5,
    },
  ],
];

const result = data.flat();
console.log(result);
```